# mocha-web-velocity console output

Tags: unit-testing, meteor, mocha.js, velocity

I just tried out the various testing frameworks that came with Meteor's velocity.  I am leaning towards using mocha, but the test results are only available via the velocity-html-reporter.  Is there a configuration to get some output to the console?  Jasmine has it by default.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you installed velocity by the following command

> mrt add velocity-quick-start

This command install the velocity-html-reporter by default. Instedt you could have installed velocity manualy by

> mrt add velocity
>
> mrt add jasmine-unit
>
> mrt add mocha-web-velocity

You can get more information by watching this video: https://www.meteor.com/blog/2014/07/15/meteor-devshop-sf-june-2014

Comment: Thanks, however I'm actually looking for a console reporter for mocha.  The presentation mentioned that Velocity can publish results to a console reporter.  I'm not sure if this is already available though. :D

Something like this, where I can view results from a terminal rather than the browser:

http://visionmedia.github.io/mocha/images/reporter-spec.png

Answer (score 0):

I just released a package to use some of Mocha's standard reporters with mike:mocha. Check it out: https://atmospherejs.com/canotto90/mocha-reporters.